# Determine the equation of a circle using one point on it and the fact that it is touching axis x

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

I need to determine the equation of a circle that:

Touches the x axis

Has a point R=[2;1]

I know I need to get the location of the middle and size of the radius to create the equation, but I am at loss of finding a way to do that.

I would probably be able to do it myself if I had some more information about the circle (like radius) but I've already spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to solve it with so little information.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That is not enough information.  Draw it, you'll see that there are infinitely many possible circles.  Indeed, taking any point $P=(a,0)$ on the $x-$axis you can construct a circle which is tangent to the axis at $P$ which passes through $(2,1)$.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. Even if the point of touch with the $x$-axis would have been given, there are an infinite number of circle passing through $2$ points.

Comment: @AbishankaSaha  Oh, if you knew the point of tangency, that would be enough.  The fact of tangency is a third bit of data.  Construct the perpendicular to the axis at the tangency point then construct the line of points equidistant from the two given points, the center of the circle is where these two lines intersect.

Comment: @lulu That's what I felt was wrong. Is there any way I go about somehow solving this then since I can't simply determine the equation? It's a homework and I don't want to be returning a blank sheet of paper.

Comment: As stated, the problem can not be solved...there is insufficient data.  Are you sure you have reprinted the problem accurately?  It doesn't, for example, specify the point of tangency?  If the data is truly insufficient, I'd suggest writing that up.  Show, for example, that there is a unique circle through the given point having any specified point of tangency with the axis (I sketched the construction in an earlier comment).

Comment: @Petrusion Is there anyone you could ask for the complete problem? There's clearly something missing.

If you can't, the best solution is probably to show that there are multiple circles with these two properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As many people have commented, there’s not enough information here to find a unique solution. If this is really the problem you’ve been given in its entirety, the best that you can do is find a family of circles that satisfy the constraints.

Since the circle is tangent to the $x$-axis, its radius must be equal to the absolute value of the center’s $y$-coordinate. Thus, the equation of a circle that fits these constraints will have the form $$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=k^2.$$ Plugging in the known point will give you a constraint on $h$ and $k$, the coordinates of the center: $$(2-h)^2+(1-k)^2 = k^2 \\
h^2+k^2-2h-2k+5 = k^2 \\
k = \frac12(h^2-4h+5)$$ therefore, any circle with a center on the parabola $\frac12(x^2-4x+5)$ with radius equal to the $y$-coordinate satisfies the problem’s constraints.